# Invalid requirements.txt on deploying django app to aws beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been deploying my app without any issues to the beanstalk environment until my latest commit.

Now I get this

```
Time    Type    Details
2013-09-01 10:19:12 UTC+0800    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
2013-09-01 10:19:11 UTC+0800    ERROR   Responses from [i-50f40d06] were received, but the commands failed.
2013-09-01 10:19:11 UTC+0800    ERROR   Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
2013-09-01 10:19:11 UTC+0800    ERROR   [Instance: i-50f40d06 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: Hook-PreAppDeploy] Failed on instance with return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed .
```

The snapshot logs say this:

```
2013-09-01 02:19:08,852 [INFO] (9941 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: New python executable in /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python2.6
Not overwriting existing python script /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python (you must use /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python2.6)
Installing distribute..................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip................done.
2013-09-01 02:19:08,564 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status -9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 31, in main
    install_dependencies()
  File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 25, in install_dependencies
    shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 502, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --use-mirrors -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status -9

2013-09-01 02:19:08,853 [ERROR] (9941 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-34] [root directoryHooksExecutor error] Script failed with returncode 1
2
```

My requirements.txt is the same as before. I tried removing everything in the requirements.txt as well but I get the same error again which makes me think the problem was before requirements.txt was run.

I don't know the order in which things are deployed. ANyway, here is my config file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    libjpeg-devel: '6b'
    zlib-devel: []
    freetype-devel: []


container_commands:
  01_install_mysqldb:
    command: "pip install distribute==0.6.28; pip install mysql-python;"
  02_syncdb:
    command: "python manage.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  03_createadmin:
    command: "python scripts/createadmin.py"
    leader_only: true
  04_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
  05_migrate_wizards:
    command: "python manage.py migrate wizards --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  06_migrate_facebook:
    command: "python manage.py migrate facebook --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  07_migrate_socialaccount:
    command: "python manage.py migrate socialaccount 0011 --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  08_migrate_missions:
    command: "python manage.py migrate missions --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  09_migrate_mailchimp:
    command: "python manage.py migrate mailchimp --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  10_migrate_actstream:
    command: "python manage.py migrate actstream --noinput"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: ideatory/wsgi.py
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles
    option_name: /static/
    value: static/
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: ideatory.settings
```

Comment: -@vaisaghvt did you solve your problem?

Comment: As @jvannistelrooy below said, the only thing that finally worked for me was rebuilding the environment.

Comment: How do you view the snapshot logs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. The only thing that worked for me was (automatically) rebuilding my entire environment. You can do that in the AWS console. Go to your environment and click Actions > Rebuild Environment. This will take some time, afterwards it will automatically relaunch your app without this error.

**Update:**

The problem keeps returning so now and then. I figured out that something is going wrong when pip compiles `psycopg`, which is needed for postgreSQL support. Haven't found a real solution yet.

Comment: did you find a solution for psycopg ? I am facing a same problem and am trying to figure it out. Thanks !

Comment: @user2608802 No, unfortunately I stopped using Elastic Beanstalk and changed my AWS setup.

Comment: This blog from realpython.com seems to have a solution: https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this problem. I encountered the exact same error after my last commit. The interesting point is that I have not changed any line of my code. The only difference is that due to changing my computer, I had to install EB again on my machine.

Comment: in order to build psycopg your environment needs postgresql93-devel (or 94, depending on your platform version)

Comment: I have postgresql 10.7 running on my local ubuntu machine. Should i add postgresql==10.7  in requirements.txt before psycopg2?

Comment: @Sandeep  Gyz have you solve this error i am still going through this error and it sucks.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to make this work by adding `postgresql93-devel` and `postgresql93` to my `.ebextensions`

*as described in **[Customizing the Software on EC2 Instances Running Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html)***

This is working for `64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9 running Python 2.7`

in `.ebextensions/01_pre_deps.config`:

```
packages:
  yum:
    gcc-c++: []
    make: []
    openssl-devel: []
    git: []
    python-devel: []
    python27-devel: []
    ruby-devel: []
    postgresql93: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
    # nginx: []
  rubygems:
    bundler: '1.7.3'
    compass-core: '1.1.0.alpha.3'
    neat-compass: '1.6.0'
```

Comment: I'm actually using a MySQL database so I don't think this solution applies.

Comment: this worked for me, all i had to add in my config file was the lines postgresql93 and postgresql93-devel under the packages/yum/ heading. I'm running this aws beanstalk

Comment: I have postgresql 10.7 running on my local ubuntu machine. Should i add postgresql10:[ ] to the .ebextensions files?

Comment: @Aseem that would make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Although a different scenario than described by the OP, it may be of use to someone:

We got the same `ERROR   Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.` message while trying to deploy a minimal test app to a newly created `t1.micro` instance on Elastic Beanstalk.

The test app consisted of the basic AWS Python sample app ([from here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/RelatedResources.html)), to which we added the `.ebextensions/software.config` and `requirements.txt` from our production environment. The sole purpose was to test these two files in deployment.

Closer inspection of the logs uncovered a `MemoryError` during `pip install`. After upgrading to a `t2.small` instance, the deployment succeeded without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure `mysql-devel` package is installed? It doesn't seem to be included in the  `yum` section of your config file.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I have mysql-devel installed.

Comment: Yep, it's installed. As I mentioned, it was working fine till this commit. No idea what went wrong, but a rebuild of the environment was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason AWS wouldn't install `postgresql-devel` packets from my `.extensions/01_packets.config` as yolk suggested. So instead I had to add

```
container_commands:
  01_addPostgreSQLPacket:
    command: 'yum install postgresql95-devel'
    leader_only: true
```

to my `02_django.config`. After That it worked just fine.