# Deploying a Django Application on Elastic Beanstak - AWS official tutorial

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've a Django app which I want to get on AWS. As I've no idea of the AWS, I tried following the official tutorial to do so.I followed this tutorial:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

However, in spite of following the tutorial in totality(also repeating it several times, I'm facing some problems with it.) Firstly, I get an error when I do the

eb create command
which are:

```html
ERROR: Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
ERROR: [Instance: i-5d0ab386] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
WARN: Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Command failed on all instances.
ERROR: Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

When I try carrying on from here, my

```
eb open
```

command does not show the Django "It worked" page
but, rather shows, Index of /

If anybody could please tell me the reason for it and what am I doing wrong then it would be really helpful.

I would also like to tell you that I've been audacious enough to run the eb deploy command even after this which fails completely.

My requirements.txt:

```
awsebcli==3.5.1
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
blessed==1.9.5
botocore==1.1.10
cement==2.4.0
colorama==0.3.3
Django==1.8.3
docker-py==1.1.0
dockerpty==0.3.4
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.12
jmespath==0.7.1
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.0
pathspec==0.3.3
pbr==1.5.0
pyasn1==0.1.8
python-dateutil==2.4.2
PyYAML==3.11
requests==2.6.2
six==1.9.0
stevedore==1.7.0
texttable==0.8.3
virtualenv==13.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.6.0
wcwidth==0.1.4
websocket-client==0.32.0
wheel==0.24.0
```

**Log files**

```html
Retrieving logs...
============= i-fdbf3f3b ==============
-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-version-deployment.log
-------------------------------------
2015-08-27 19:38:22,465 [INFO] Found the latest version manifest file <Key: elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-811805444315,resources/environments/e-yqiwjpydgq/_runtime/versions/manifest_1440704126698> from bucket elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-811805444315 and prefix resources/environments/e-yqiwjpydgq/_runtime/versions/
2015-08-27 19:38:22,518 [INFO] Downloaded the manifest file to /tmp/version_file_manifest
2015-08-27 19:38:22,608 [INFO] Downloaded version label app-150828_010528 from s3 key <Key: elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-811805444315,resources/environments/e-yqiwjpydgq/_runtime/_versions/eb_django_app6/app-150828_010528>



-------------------------------------
/opt/python/log/httpd.out
-------------------------------------




-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Thu Aug 27 20:01:01.438567 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2524] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Aug 27 20:01:01.439596 2015] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2524] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Aug 27 20:01:01.441269 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2524] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 27 20:01:01.441292 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2524] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'



-------------------------------------
/opt/python/log/supervisord.log
-------------------------------------
2015-08-27 19:38:30,364 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2015-08-27 19:38:30,392 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2015-08-27 19:38:30,392 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-08-27 19:38:30,392 INFO supervisord started with pid 2447
2015-08-27 19:38:31,394 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 2524
2015-08-27 19:38:32,396 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)



-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/access_log
-------------------------------------
172.31.40.113 - - [27/Aug/2015:20:12:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 161 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2015-08-27T19:39:37.012Z] INFO  [2539]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity failed.
[2015-08-27T19:39:37.012Z] INFO  [2539]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2015-08-27T19:39:37.012Z] INFO  [2539]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0] : Activity failed.
[2015-08-27T19:39:37.013Z] INFO  [2539]  - [Application deployment] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup(stage 0) failed
[2015-08-27T19:42:53.486Z] INFO  [2814]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T19:42:53.715Z] INFO  [2814]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T19:42:53.715Z] INFO  [2814]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T19:42:53.715Z] INFO  [2814]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T19:42:53.715Z] INFO  [2814]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T19:42:54.112Z] INFO  [2814]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T19:42:54.112Z] INFO  [2814]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2015-08-27T19:42:54.112Z] INFO  [2814]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T19:42:54.112Z] INFO  [2814]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T19:42:54.112Z] INFO  [2814]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage  - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2015-08-27T20:04:48.641Z] INFO  [3445]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:04:48.866Z] INFO  [3445]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:04:48.866Z] INFO  [3445]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:04:48.866Z] INFO  [3445]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:04:48.866Z] INFO  [3445]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:04:49.203Z] INFO  [3445]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:04:49.203Z] INFO  [3445]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2015-08-27T20:04:49.203Z] INFO  [3445]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:04:49.203Z] INFO  [3445]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:04:49.203Z] INFO  [3445]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage  - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2015-08-27T20:05:31.392Z] INFO  [3483]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:05:31.621Z] INFO  [3483]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:05:31.621Z] INFO  [3483]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:05:31.621Z] INFO  [3483]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:05:31.621Z] INFO  [3483]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:05:31.819Z] INFO  [3483]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:05:31.819Z] INFO  [3483]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2015-08-27T20:05:31.819Z] INFO  [3483]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:05:31.819Z] INFO  [3483]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:05:31.819Z] INFO  [3483]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage  - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2015-08-27T20:08:22.498Z] INFO  [3596]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:08:22.777Z] INFO  [3596]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:08:22.777Z] INFO  [3596]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:08:22.777Z] INFO  [3596]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:08:22.778Z] INFO  [3596]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:08:22.985Z] INFO  [3596]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:08:22.985Z] INFO  [3596]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2015-08-27T20:08:22.985Z] INFO  [3596]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:08:22.985Z] INFO  [3596]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:08:22.985Z] INFO  [3596]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage  - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.065Z] INFO  [3724]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.291Z] INFO  [3724]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.291Z] INFO  [3724]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.291Z] INFO  [3724]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.292Z] INFO  [3724]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.474Z] INFO  [3724]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.474Z] INFO  [3724]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.474Z] INFO  [3724]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.474Z] INFO  [3724]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.474Z] INFO  [3724]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage  - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.180Z] INFO  [3763]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.405Z] INFO  [3763]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.405Z] INFO  [3763]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.405Z] INFO  [3763]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.405Z] INFO  [3763]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.588Z] INFO  [3763]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.588Z] INFO  [3763]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.588Z] INFO  [3763]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.588Z] INFO  [3763]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.588Z] INFO  [3763]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage  - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] INFO  [3932]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] INFO  [3932]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] INFO  [3932]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] INFO  [3932]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] INFO  [3932]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.953Z] INFO  [3932]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.953Z] INFO  [3932]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.953Z] INFO  [3932]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.953Z] INFO  [3932]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.953Z] INFO  [3932]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage  - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] INFO  [26357] - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.731Z] INFO  [26357] - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.731Z] INFO  [26357] - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.732Z] INFO  [26357] - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.732Z] INFO  [26357] - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.291Z] INFO  [3724]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.291Z] DEBUG [3724]  : Setting environment variables..
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.291Z] INFO  [3724]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.291Z] DEBUG [3724]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.291Z] INFO  [3724]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.292Z] DEBUG [3724]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.292Z] INFO  [3724]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.474Z] INFO  [3724]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.474Z] INFO  [3724]  : Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded!
[2015-08-27T20:12:41.475Z] INFO  [3724]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"[Instance: i-fdbf3f3b] Successfully finished tailing 7 log(s)","severity":"INFO","timestamp":1440706361475}]}]}
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.178Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.178Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.179Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-fdbf3f3b)..
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.179Z] INFO  [3763]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-fdbf3f3b)..
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.179Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.179Z] INFO  [3763]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.179Z] INFO  [3763]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAJRM425VDSY5UWQ7Q\",\"policy\":\"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\",\"security_token\":\"AQoDYXdzEE0asAIkC+k6nAIzWvcXa+FFJsSM+qhH1wmFE0Gx74CVLFMSZVfMj2YAu6FBMlfV6nGYmYK18ymAckhnnaSRXKL1xfUVVwrvJxrfCxRV5WRlN1lyHYpXAKwmffJZbjZWgeDB+N4GftI1b\\\/fUH\\\/x5d5yFZDrU9SC6011kU5GnYuSqq6xD+j7hJGAe0oC+F7J3X1MtcHHQsq6arO63VNKSR2rPKZe1RwxE092uiESmxxsECRUIzTyjLozV52R1cGTgg66r4YElIaaiuh6E3YQSV4qtRtOaHtApl03b755P3An+YqiDwEjJxvYK55n5wcvYYk7BPZmwuSXC4wpMXIgNW\\\/3IBA3sbUMnlAt\\\/GWOILr\\\/dVqCqsl\\\/+VO+kclHnMlqDlOjyr93X3akfsEkJ9mQuXm2NzsfXIOje\\\/a4F\",\"signature\":\"9PYN5I1zyrleb19yylouL6+DCRM=\"}","request_id":"14739ebc-4cf8-11e5-a3cc-2b6ea86f4160","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","data":"14739ebc-4cf8-11e5-a3cc-2b6ea86f4160","instance_ids":["i-fdbf3f3b"],"command_timeout":"600","api_version":"1.0"}
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.179Z] INFO  [3763]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.179Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Storing current stage..
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.179Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.179Z] INFO  [3763]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs - stage 
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.180Z] INFO  [3763]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.180Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.180Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Refreshing metadata..
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.402Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Refreshed environment metadata.
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.402Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.403Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.403Z] INFO  [3763]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.404Z] INFO  [3763]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.404Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.404Z] INFO  [3763]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.405Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Setting environment variables..
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.405Z] INFO  [3763]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.405Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.405Z] INFO  [3763]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.405Z] DEBUG [3763]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.405Z] INFO  [3763]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.588Z] INFO  [3763]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.588Z] INFO  [3763]  : Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded!
[2015-08-27T20:13:30.589Z] INFO  [3763]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"[Instance: i-fdbf3f3b] Successfully finished tailing 7 log(s)","severity":"INFO","timestamp":1440706410589}]}]}
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.532Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.532Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-fdbf3f3b)..
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] INFO  [3932]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-fdbf3f3b)..
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] INFO  [3932]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] INFO  [3932]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAJL3KZZKMQMNYAGDA\",\"policy\":\"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\",\"security_token\":\"AQoDYXdzEE0asAKhdneEAx7bTtIcmxomENuq47Wyo2jj+j\\\/NhTGXRKAa7idLBMveXcGhxCGwZQjrdcoKYQLxNuk9kR3sVKePqnIKpxlPFqu+vMR4kV4xV2kYhamJeRoZdKTy0mnuBdJ4TZiQaS\\\/HqTL\\\/YNp5S1ekQrRe9S+BlE5r5BOmy+eqhuph0xDV8MxcRpTdleR+x4XuvLbWpusZkGb1BzKblbhXQ4HLSpiFR9IXM6cPh0JYtIblU1U+3ARmIV8nwh33O5Yyfiz9O1G3wPN\\\/fS41NkqTpPiPXdQd6aA5y+AM4BqJt5VSVG\\\/7Mo7dgKmfFtVlEhN0ZuyfX4mTbPZop9Gx9A6T42nFeYTZUqYp6GUCd5cMjXSlX2TtOe\\\/Z+Fgg1ulUvfcbnsVOf0TV60XVW0V68QNbhySmIN3h\\\/a4F\",\"signature\":\"+YGmi++z2osIC7LTabwjnIyh9uY=\"}","request_id":"f2d5dae8-4cf8-11e5-a3cc-2b6ea86f4160","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","data":"f2d5dae8-4cf8-11e5-a3cc-2b6ea86f4160","instance_ids":["i-fdbf3f3b"],"command_timeout":"600","api_version":"1.0"}
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] INFO  [3932]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Storing current stage..
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] INFO  [3932]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs - stage 
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] INFO  [3932]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.534Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.535Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Refreshing metadata..
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.758Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Refreshed environment metadata.
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.758Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.759Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.759Z] INFO  [3932]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] INFO  [3932]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] INFO  [3932]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Setting environment variables..
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] INFO  [3932]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] INFO  [3932]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] DEBUG [3932]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.761Z] INFO  [3932]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.953Z] INFO  [3932]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.953Z] INFO  [3932]  : Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded!
[2015-08-27T20:19:43.954Z] INFO  [3932]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"[Instance: i-fdbf3f3b] Successfully finished tailing 7 log(s)","severity":"INFO","timestamp":1440706783954}]}]}
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.503Z] DEBUG [26357] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.504Z] DEBUG [26357] : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] DEBUG [26357] : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-fdbf3f3b)..
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] INFO  [26357] : Command is applicable to this instance (i-fdbf3f3b)..
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] DEBUG [26357] : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] INFO  [26357] : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] INFO  [26357] : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAJIWLKMFVFRLDNFDQ\",\"policy\":\"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\",\"security_token\":\"AQoDYXdzEE4asAKBhjmpfEOOl66woIKg8wC4fbYApxVgLYfQBjQTptpo8Ck174+V6rFRYMFAufOH\\\/Qo7LXwR6u4W56vcqGrHT\\\/xKTwW8\\\/A8F6Taxn1FQnVm7byH3s3jzaYB9gh9jmJ3CflCp9VTwoMBW5rydEuDWoCuhdisV2KHa17hSX2y2ZEnlyUQc1za6Bs8bQX65KtkeiumsBxUIAX2XEhuATdyZFKf3DvCLXUtP39inuHw7zL6MaRCcgDCG6+gvV2y+Mntp17Z95l2lRGAa8QOMaJqVkr0OZcwluUjHOIjQUCei5iUDuel\\\/5mGiIVXOO0HQPdalZOAEPq1iXFr+XwY+ZFW0mw\\\/ENfEnvW2gfx1bmQ3i41SuJDtsvKVG6To6ZMr\\\/jXA0MRMIm9HDHjAh5mucKTeFHcydILvu\\\/a4F\",\"signature\":\"3eO+lrrf6eiRWg\\\/cTQM9vNLIAFs=\"}","request_id":"be56d7a8-4cfc-11e5-a0a8-8718d714af7d","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","data":"be56d7a8-4cfc-11e5-a0a8-8718d714af7d","instance_ids":["i-fdbf3f3b"],"command_timeout":"600","api_version":"1.0"}
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] INFO  [26357] : Command processor should execute command.
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] DEBUG [26357] : Storing current stage..
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] DEBUG [26357] : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] INFO  [26357] : Executing CMD-TailLogs - stage 
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] INFO  [26357] : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.506Z] DEBUG [26357] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.507Z] DEBUG [26357] : Refreshing metadata..
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.729Z] DEBUG [26357] : Refreshed environment metadata.
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.729Z] DEBUG [26357] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.729Z] DEBUG [26357] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.730Z] INFO  [26357] : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.731Z] INFO  [26357] : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.731Z] DEBUG [26357] : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.731Z] INFO  [26357] : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.731Z] DEBUG [26357] : Setting environment variables..
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.731Z] INFO  [26357] : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.732Z] DEBUG [26357] : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.732Z] INFO  [26357] : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.732Z] DEBUG [26357] : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2015-08-27T20:46:53.732Z] INFO  [26357] : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

Comment: What is in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Added it have a look @BurhanKhalid

Comment: Finally, paste the output of [`eb logs`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-logs.html), the exact error is there.

Comment: Check /var/log/eb-activity.log but guessing that pip install failed. Any way to check that pip is actually on the instance?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid added the log files check.

Comment: @jarmod I've no clue either am a complete beginner with AWS, Ive added the logs though check if it is of any use

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554666/invalid-requirements-txt-on-deploying-django-app-to-aws-beanstalk.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem. Can anything else be inferred from the logs?

Comment: If the logs aren't sufficient to identify the problem (they don't seem to be) then I would consider manually SSHing onto the instance and running pip install against the uploaded requirements.txt to see why it is failing.