# ERROR: Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**I am new to AWS CLI USAGE. So do explain me the error clearly so that i don't make that mistake next time.**

> Here is my requirements.txt file :

```
    appdirs==1.4.3
    cssselect==1.0.1
    dj-database-url==0.4.2
    Django==1.11
    django-ckeditor==5.2.2
    Markdown==2.6.8
    packaging==16.8
    psycopg2==2.5.4
    pyparsing==2.2.0
    pytz==2017.2
    six==1.10.0
```

> Here are my files inside .ebextensions directory :

- **django.config**

  ```
  option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "awsbean.settings"
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
      WSGIPath: cv_web/wsgi.py
  ```
- **packages.config**

  ```
  packages:
    yum:
      git: []
  ```
- **python.config**

  ```
  container_commands:
     01_migrate:
      command: "python src/manage.py migrate --noinput"
      leader_only: true
  ```

> And here is my config.yml file inside .ebextensions/.elasticbeanstalk
>   :

```
 branch-defaults:
     default:
        environment: environment
    environment-defaults:
      environment:
        branch: null
        repository: null
    global:
      application_name: cv_web
      default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb2
      default_platform: Python 3.4
      default_region: ap-south-1
      instance_profile: null
      platform_name: null
      platform_version: null
      profile: eb-cli
      sc: null
      workspace_type: Application
```

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554666/invalid-requirements-txt-on-deploying-django-app-to-aws-beanstalk

Comment: I tried it but didn't helped :-( @jarmod

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue with `psycopg2` on AWS. You have to manually sudo install it.

What I usually do is I include the psycopg2 install (reqires installing `postgressql-devel` first) in `.ebextensions` so to make sure it's available before `requirements.txt` kicks off.

Include this in your config file:

```
container_commands:
  01_postgresql:
    command: sudo yum -y install gcc python-setuptools python-devel postgresql-devel
  02_postgresql:
    command: sudo easy_install psycopg2
```