# requirements.txt Issues while deploying Django on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, requirements.txt

I am trying to deploy a Django APP on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but i have been dealing with this requirements.txt file invalid error for hours. Please any help would be apppreciated

```
Erros Trace:
2019-11-04 11:57:47    ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

ERROR: ServiceError - Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

Find below my requirements.txt file

requirements.txt

```
blessed==1.16.1
botocore==1.12.253
cached-property==1.5.1
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2019.9.11
cffi==1.7.0
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.9
Django==2.2.6
django-appconf==1.0.3
django-select2==7.1.1
docker==3.7.3
docker-compose==1.23.2
docker-pycreds==0.4.0
dockerpty==0.4.1
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.15.2
future==0.16.0
idna==2.7
jmespath==0.9.4
jsonschema==2.6.0
pathspec==0.5.9
pycparser==2.19
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-decouple==3.1
python-magic==0.4.15
python-magic-bin==0.4.14
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==3.13
requests==2.20.1
semantic-version==2.5.0
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
termcolor==1.1.0
texttable==0.9.1
urllib3==1.24.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
websocket-client==0.56.0
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554666/invalid-requirements-txt-on-deploying-django-app-to-aws-beanstalk?

Comment: @nik_m.. Yes.. not same issue, as i dont have postgres in my requirements.txt file

Comment: Did you check the log file referenced in the output for more details (/var/log/eb-activity.log)?  It would certainly help us all help you if you include the relevant parts of that log in your question.  Also plz share the contents of your requirements file.