# Can't deploy EB Django Application

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Here's my full error after I run eb deploy:

```
Creating application version archive "app-210816_201313".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2021-08-17 01:13:46    INFO    Environment update is starting.
2021-08-17 01:13:51    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2021-08-17 01:14:06    ERROR   Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
2021-08-17 01:14:10    ERROR   [Instance: i-0995f885df1f382cb] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2021-08-17 01:14:10    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2021-08-17 01:14:10    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0995f885df1f382cb'. Aborting the operation.
2021-08-17 01:14:10    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

Here's my requirements.txt file:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
autopep8==1.5.7
awsebcli==3.20.1
backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.0
botocore==1.21.22
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2021.5.30
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
distlib==0.3.2
Django==3.2.6
filelock==3.0.12
future==0.16.0
idna==3.2
jmespath==0.10.0
pathspec==0.5.9
pipenv==2021.5.29
platformdirs==2.2.0
pycodestyle==2.7.0
pypiwin32==223
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.1
pywin32==301
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.26.0
semantic-version==2.8.5
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
termcolor==1.1.0
toml==0.10.2
urllib3==1.25.11
virtualenv==20.7.0
virtualenv-clone==0.5.6
wcwidth==0.1.9
```

I tried `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` and then deploying again, but same error as shown above. How do I fix this? How do I access my logs? thanks in advance. I restarted from the ground up but same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20973301/8401179

Comment: Some of the libraries in your requirements are not meant to deploy (virtualenv, virtualenv-clone, awsebcli, botocore, autopep8, ...). Maybe try to create a separate requirements for development and production, and then try again?

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın how can I tell which are not meant to deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed this problem by running

```
python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

in my virtual environment and not just my project directory.

But the overall problem is not this. I think the problem is because the free version is depreciated and can't deal with my new stuff.